# Image Slideshow with description text and no timer

Tags: web-part, image-display

Image Slideshow with description text and no timer

This sounds simple and its available as OOTB WebPart in SPS2013.
However, in my case i dont want:

- Any timer and the image should only change when the page refreshes.
- Using the OOTB picture Slideshow WebPart, lot of spacing at edge,
  tried to reduce it using CSS, still not that appealing.

Any image slideshow that looks better with no timer?

Answer (score 0):

I used the Image Slider example at Sharegate web site here. http://en.share-gate.com/blog/image-slider-with-sharepoint-2013-search-results

basically, it is using the search results web part with custom display template (SlideJS library + jQuery).

if for whatever reason, you are more comfortable with other library, like the ones here at http://www.jssor.com/ (choose the one you like and you can tweak the custom display template provided by Sharegate)

Comment: Image slider by ShareGate for whatever reason doesnt works in my SPS2013 environment. ANy other suggestion that can allow a picture library with image change at refresh rather a timer?

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: which part did not work? The query is not returning results from the Picture Library or the sliding effect is not working? They way I got it to work was to make sure I understand how the sliding/javascript works (forget SharePoint)..Once you get the idea and understand what should go in the UL vs what should go in the li, the conversion process is easy). the everything in the UL should go to the control item display template, and li goes into the item display template.